# Making log message priority show up in syslog

Tags: logging, redhat-enterprise-linux, priority, syslog

I'm using Red Hat 6.0 on a testing server. My code contains

```
syslog(pri,"(%u)%s",(unsigned int)getTid(),buf);
```

The log message in `syslog` looks like

> (18597)DES=Recved confirmation of successful reception from 172.16.88.185:8889.

How can I configure `syslog.conf` to make log message priority show up in `syslog`?

**Edit:**
`getTid` is the function I used to get the thread id; `buf(const char*)` is a variable I used for the log message, `pri` is the log level I set, e.g. `LOG_ERR`, `LOG_DEBUG`, &c.

When I ask about "log message priority," I mean `LOG_ERR`, `LOG_INFO`, &c.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm doing some gravedigging here, but for the record you can run `sysklogd` with `-S` to include a numeric facility and priority value. `-SS` includes the names.

Answer (score 0):

Your syslogd or sysklogd may not be able to do this. `rsyslog` can do that, see http://www.rsyslog.com/